# How to get data into the table from API using Angular services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have updated the code and the output I am getting like this:

[image: Updated]

So in the output table, endTime, period and monday are headers. For EndTime I want to display only endtime of the monday array but it is displaying an entire array. How do I specifically display only endTime data. Same goes for period.

Here is the plunker [Timetable](https://plnkr.co/edit/KviWA4o0TBwI2kkYtTny?p=preview)

Where am I going wrong?

**Index.view.html**

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th class="endTime" ng-model="monday.endTime">End Time</th>
      <td ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">{{d}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="period" ng-model="monday.period">Peroid</th>
      <td ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">{{d}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><th class="days">Monday</th></tr>
  </table>
```

**Index.controller.js**

```
        .controller('Admin.IndexController',function($scope,$http,$location,$rootScope,fileUpload)
    {                         
       $scope.college_id='583b01ce6864990011c12ec6';
        var i =0;       
        $http.get('https://student.herokuapp.com/college/'+$scope.college_id)
        .success(function(response){
             // for(var i=0;i<tableLen;i++){
                console.log(response.college);
            $scope.data = response.college.timeTableTemplate;
            console.log($scope.data);
         });           

        })
```

**JSON Array**

```
    "monday": [
    {
      "endTime": "08:50 AM",
      "startTime": "08:00 AM",
      "duration": "50",
      "period": "A"
    },
    {
      "endTime": "08:50 AM",
      "startTime": "08:00 AM",
      "duration": "50",
      "period": "A"
    }
```

Comment: Where you added `ng-repeat` directive?

Comment: I did add the ng-repeat but didnt get the desired results.

Comment: If you can add plunkr or jsfiddle, it will be faster for you to get this answered.

Comment: Desired results means you want vertical rows correct?

Comment: @AnuragSinha Ok I will add it

Comment: @AvneshShakya not the vertical rows I mean the horizontal data after the headers period, timings and monday. Horizontaal data for Period is I,II...IX etc and similarly for timings

Comment: @AnuragSinha Added plunker

Comment: In your plunker there is so many errors.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh corrected it

Comment: update your question with new plukr

Comment: @DurgpalSingh updated

Comment: your link https://withstudent.herokuapp.com/college/ is not display any record. Problem is in your link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131661/discussion-between-durgpal-singh-and-heblev).

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your json structure to in this type

```
{  
  "endTime": ["08:50 AM", "08:50 AM", "08:50 AM"],
  "startTime": "[08:00 AM, 08:00 AM, 08:00 AM]",
  "duration": ["50", "50", "50"],
  "period": ["A", "A", "A"]
}
```

I create a plunker there you can see I got the data from json and display in table tag. Please read this and apply in your code.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
      <td >{{ d.id }}</td>
      <td >{{ d.firstName }}</td>
      <td >{{ d.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fF3wYWGv8F1UGPUyjtrW?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Thank you for the efforts. I see that headers is in horizontal format. I made them in vertical format but unable to include the data with related headers. Check the plunk.

Comment: I am updating my plunker. please check this.

Comment: Thank you. I checked it and when I used the code, I could see the value in response and but not in $scope.data during debug. Any reason?

Comment: value also in $scope.data. You can console the value of $scope.data and if it is helpful and click right of this answer.

Comment: data.endTime and data.period works in plnkr but not working with my code and when i remove the endTime and period entire json data is printed.

Comment: its not possible if you remove endTime and peroid in json and then they display in html page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131653/discussion-between-heblev-and-durgpal-singh).

Comment: Hey json structure was correct. I made changes in the frontend <td ng-repeat="d in data.sunday">{{ d.startTime}}</td> to same json strucutre. Thanks for your efforts.